# Apache Spark logging extended plan

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to log `df.explain(true)`
I would like to see physical and logical plan.
I didn't find anywhere on the documentation how to do that using the `log4j.properties` looking at the source code it seems like they use `println()` for printing which means they use standard output.

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an issue on spark JIRA  : [SPARK-18829](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18829) for this question.
For now you can print explain plan using,

```
df.queryExecution.toString
```

this code return a String with Physical/ analayed / Logical plans